# Password validation with CSS

Tags: css, passwords

For some students I have made some simple password validation hacks in html and javascript
Now I wonder whether I can make a password validation, only using html and css (so without the javascript)?

I understand that css is not used for form validation, only for modifying some props like colors, as a reaction to the validation process. However the html input pattern and type attributes are.
I dont know where to put the last two sentences - here, as a comment or as an answer, so here it is. Cheers

Comment: You need to show us that you have tried, yourself.

Comment: simple search will lead you to tutorials like this: https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-form-validation/

Comment: To get better answers and prevent down votes you need to show what you have tried, what has worked and what hasn't. Please see this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question so you get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the HTML5 `pattern` attribute ([see here for more information](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#attr-input-pattern)), which allows you to define allowed patterns as regular expressions. Keep in mind that this is not supported by all browsers.

An `input` element for emails could look like this:

```html
<input type="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" />
```

You can then use CSS to give the user feedback, if the value of the field is invalid:

```css
input:invalid {
    border-color: red;
}

input:valid {
    border-color: green;
}
```

Comment: This works or me, as does the link from DohaHelmy. Thx